# Apt-get install r-base installing R version 2.15, not R 3.0

Tags: r, ubuntu, apt-get

I'm installing R on an Ubuntu 12.10 x64 and when I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

And I am getting R version 2.15.1.

Shouldn't this get me the most recent version R 3.0.2?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/352438/215709

Comment: or more directly http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software installation/administration

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476713/how-to-upgrade-r-in-ubuntu/10476798#10476798

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically gave up and switched to Ubuntu 13.10 and when I used apt-get to install base R I got version 3 as expected.

It was related somehow the version 12 Ubuntu I was using.